# How to allow duplicate entry, SQLSTATE[23000] in Symfony2?

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

For example, I have product [Banana] and product [orange] I would like both products to use the same picture in the database. But when I tried to add a second product with the same picture as the first product I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
> '1' for key 'UNIQ_5A8A6C8D3DA5256D'

My Media Entity:

```
 <?php

namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity;
use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * Media
 *
 * @ORM\Table("media")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\MediaRepository")
 */
class Media
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=125)
     */
    private $alt;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * Set alt
     *
     * @param string $alt
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setAlt($alt)
    {
        $this->alt = $alt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get alt
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAlt()
    {
        return $this->alt;
    }
}
```

My Post Entity:

```
   <?php

namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\Secure;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */

    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $image;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text" , length=125)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="airport", type="string")
     */

    protected $airport;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="airport1", type="string")
     */

    protected $airport1;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="departuredate", type="datetime")
     */
    private $departuredate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="arrivaldate", type="datetime")
     */
    private $arrivaldate;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="pounds", type="float")
     */
    private $pounds;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float")
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     *
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @Security("user.getId() == post.getUser()")
     */
    private $user;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Set airport
     *
     * @param array $airport
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setAirport($airport)
    {
        $this->airport = $airport;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get airport
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAirport()
    {
        return $this->airport;
    }

    /**
     * Set airport1
     *
     * @param array $airport1
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setAirport1($airport1)
    {
        $this->airport1 = $airport1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get airport1
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAirport1()
    {
        return $this->airport1;
    }


    /**
     * Set departuredate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $departuredate
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setDeparturedate($departuredate)
    {
        $this->departuredate = $departuredate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get departuredate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDeparturedate()
    {
        return $this->departuredate;
    }

    /**
     * Set arrivaldate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $arrivaldate
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setArrivaldate($arrivaldate)
    {
        $this->arrivaldate = $arrivaldate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get arrivaldate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getArrivaldate()
    {
        return $this->arrivaldate;
    }

  

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param float $price
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

   



    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /*
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }


   

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param \FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Media $image
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setImage(\FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Media $image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return \FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Media
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

  

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of post sql, you should post your entities. that's the way we can help you.

EDIT: Also, you got    `ADD UNIQUE KEY 'UNIQ_5A8A6C8D3DA5256D' ('image_id') ` on your post table that's why you got this error

Comment: You're using a `OneToOne`-Association on your `image` property (one post has exactly one image associated). Change it to a `ManyToOne` (many posts can have the same image). See: [Link](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like said in comment, a `one-to-one` association involves you cannot have two `Post` with the same `Media` associated.

To allow this, change your association from :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $image;
```

To :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Media", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $image;
```